# How to automatically move the various HUBsection?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an app Windows Phone 8.

There is the possibility, in the hub to press a button and have the app automatically moves to the next hubsection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `HubName.ScrollToSection(HubSectionName);`

[MSDN: Hub.ScrollToSection method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.scrolltosection)

Minimal Example

```
<Hub x:Name="myHub">
    <HubSection x:Name="myHubSection">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="2000" Height="1000">
                <TextBlock Text="hi"></TextBlock>
                <Button Content="ScrollToNext" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    <HubSection x:Name="myHubSection2">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="900">
                <TextBlock Text="hi2"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>            
</Hub>
```

---

```
// this will scroll to myHubSection2
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.myHub.ScrollToSection(this.myHubSection2);
}
```

Comment: There is also a way to change the HubSection more slowly?

Comment: @prova2 ofcourse, see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1b667e9e-012c-4688-9711-87230337a621/making-the-windows-8-hub-control-scroll-better-programmatic-gestures?forum=winappswithcsharp